# How to disable the today and the previous day in jquery ui datepicker and all the selectables will be ahead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using the datepicker in jquery and my little problem is I want to disable the previous dates and the only active links to the calendar are start from tomorrow.

Here's my little code.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label><span class="required">* </span><?php echo $entry_event_date; ?></label>
   <input type="text" name="event_date" class="form-control date" value="<?php echo $event_date; ?>" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" />
   <?php if ($error_event_date) { ?>
       <span class="error"><?php echo $error_event_date; ?></span>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
```

And my jquery code is:

```
$('.date').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it by using this simple code :)

```
$('.date').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
  minDate: 0, 
});
```